# Can we override spring.handlers file

Tags: java, spring

Spring security Oauth2 uses spring.handler file which contains

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2=org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.OAuth2SecurityNamespaceHandler
```

However I need to use my own NamespaceHandler instead of OAuth2SecurityNamespaceHandler for oauth. I tried creating a spring.handler file in my project with my namespace handler but it didn't worked.

Is their any way to override the Namespace Handler.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I want oauth to use my NamespaceHandler instead of  OAuth2SecurityNamespaceHandler. However the request is not coming to my Handler.

Comment: The reason I want to override the handler is because OauthHandler  uses RestTemplateBeanDefinitionParser which creates some session scope d beans but my application is stateless.

Comment: There's no mechanism for doing this (other than building your own jar), and it's not a good idea.